# I'm visiting Tokyo now

Tags: meaning

If someone says,

> "I'm visiting Tokyo now,"

does it mean they are already in Tokyo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It certainly implies that the person is visiting Tokyo at present.

But the sentence could also be used in other contexts, for example:

If the person was merely passing through the airport;

If the person was visiting Tokyo next.

Or

If the person was playing a computer game involving various cities.

**Tokyo** might even be somebody's name.

**Now** is a notoriously fickle word. **I'll do it now** or **just now** is a commitment frequently honoured in the breach.

In short, you can't be certain that the statement is meant literally.

Comment: Thanks, so my gut feeling about its vagueness was correct. From the context, I can **now** safely assume they're in the city for the New Year's eve.